# Notation for Linear Algebra

Tags: linear-algebra, summation, notation

Considering $B$ a basis for a subspace $U$, is the notation below correct to describe any point $X \in U$?

$$
x = \sum_{i=1}^{dim(u)} \alpha_{i} \cdot V_{i} : \alpha_{i} \in R, V_{i} \in B
$$

Answer (score 0):

Just replace $B$ by span($B$) and the answer is yes.

Comment: But the $V_{i}$ vectors is in the set of B, since B is a linearly independent set, a basis for U... why is that incorrect?

Comment: Ah yes you are right. Sorry about that .. I didn't see the word "Basis". You are right then